# Behavior of Saha and Boltzmann

Tags: astrophysics

So I'm just wondering why the Saha and Boltzmann distributions behave differently as temperature increases?

I know one is for ionization levels while the other is for energy levels but is that the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely due to a combination of two reasons, one of which you already mentioned:

1. As you state, the [Saha equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) relates the ionization levels while the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics) deals with the energy levels
2. The Saha equation incorporates quantum mechanical effects in deriving it's equation while the Maxwell-Boltzmann consider quantum effects negligible.

I recommend checking out *Fundamentals of Plasma Physics* by J Bittencourt, as the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution and Saha ionization equations are well covered in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The Saha equation takes into account free electrons considering the Heisenberg uncertainty princple and Pauli exclusion princple.  See: http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~mboett/astro401_fall12/saha.pdf